# Firebase hosted website won't load (but loads locally)

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I've built a react app beginning with create-react-app that appears to be working fine in local development. I've uploaded it to firebase hosting using firebase deploy, and the hosted version works fine when I load it using chrome on my computer, but the hosted site fails to load using firefox or any other browser. The hosted site also fails to load using any browser, including chrome, on other machines.

Here's the link to the hosted site: https://physics-coach.firebaseapp.com/
Here's the link to the github repo for this site: https://github.com/occam98/physicscoach2

I've tried toubleshooting using the developer tools, but I can't seem to make much headway—the only message I get in the console when the site fails to load is:

> It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS
>   SDK. When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to
>   only import the individual SDK components you intend to use.
>
> For the CDN builds, these are available in the following manner
>   (replace  with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database,
>   etc):
>
> https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.0/firebase-.js
>   rollbar.min.js:2:24504

I'd appreciate any troubleshooting advice about how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing your `firebase.json` contents to:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/service-worker.js",
        "headers": [{ "key": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache" }]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Your current `firebase.json` points to folder `"public"`, which will not actually contain any HTML/JS/CSS assets from running command `npm run build`. `create-react-app` [production build](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/production-build#docsNav)  command `npm run build` generates all the compiled HTML/JS/CSS resources to directory `"build"`:

> npm run build creates a build directory with a production build of
>   your app. Inside the build/static directory will be your JavaScript
>   and CSS files. Each filename inside of build/static will contain a
>   unique hash of the file contents. This hash in the file name enables
>   long term caching techniques.

Update the configuration, execute `npm run build` followed by `firebase deploy` to re-build and re-deploy.

This example also includes configuration to [exclude service worker files](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#firebase-https-firebasegooglecom) as well as rewrite rules for the purposes of using a router such as `react-router-dom`. You can remove them if they do not apply to your project in any way.

**Update:**
Also in `constants.js` you should update your Firebase imports to the following to resolve the warning. This assumes you are using Firebase Auth and Firebase Realtime Database:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: That worked. Thanks! Curious—why would the hosted app load on chrome on my machine but not on firefox on the same machine?

Comment: First, I'd recommend to resolve the warning from firebase. You are currently importing as `import firebase from "firebase";` when you instead should be importing as `import firebase from 'firebase/app'; import 'firebase/auth';` for example (or any other packages you are using). Next, it looks like you have already deployed the application with service worker being registered without the configuration for not caching the headers mentioned in my answer. It loaded fine for me in firefox because it was my first time loading it, but for you, you'd need to hard reload/clear cache.