# Firebase website renders on my computer but not any other devices

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm a first time Firebase user.  I recently tried deploying my React app on Firebase, at the url: https://surgery-labeller.firebaseapp.com/.  The website successfully renders on my computer on Chrome and Firefox.  However, it fails to load on my computer on Safari, and fails to load on any of my friends' computers (including on Chrome/Firefox).  I found a previous query for this same issue ([Firebase hosted website won't load (but loads locally)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56264516/firebase-hosted-website-wont-load-but-loads-locally)).  I made sure to implement the suggested changes (ensuring that 'public' points to 'build' in firebase.json).  However, the issue still persists: my website still doesn't load on Safari or on other devices.

Would anyone have any ideas/suggestions for what the problem could be? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I tried to load your site and saw it made a request to `localhost`, no one can access your `localhost` from their PC.

Comment: were you using the local emulators to test your code? if so, you may have forgotten to change references to the local localhost emulated versions of your functions to their actual production URLs. and if you are serving your app from a function, then you would get nothing